# I'd like to group applications based on my own conditions

Tags: windows, process-control

I'm working on a Windows-10 computer as a support engineer for my software company. This means that regularly, I get a ticket for which I need to open different Visual Studio instances, different Windbg instances, ..., and soon it becomes quite messy to find out which Visual Studio/Windbg session corresponds with which ticket.

Therefore I'd like to have an application, where I can add entries, give them a ticket number, and add/remove application instances, which make it easier to find my way back. Obviously when double-clicking such an item should put the focus on that particular application instance.

The possibility to have the corresponding ticket groups in my taskbar would be very interesting, but it's not a must.

I've already asked this question on the [Superuser forum](https://superuser.com/questions/1360228/group-processes-in-the-taskbar-is-this-possible), but as I get no answers there, I decided to try here.

Does anybody know if such software already exists?

Comment: Windows 10 introduced multiple desktops how about running one for each ticket?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: thanks for the quick reply, but there are some drawbacks about multiple desktops: there are maximum four of them and they are impossible to identify, even for having a different background on each desktop you need external software.

Comment: Them perhaps you could ask for virtual desktop app which meets your needs?

Comment: Not really : virtual desktops have the drawback that you don't see your other applications on them (like a text editor, a calculator, a spreadsheet, shared for all tickets for doing basic number and string manipulation). In top of this, the maximum number of virtual desktops is limited to four (which seems hardcoded).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you could try Windows 10 newly introduced multiple desktops feature to categorize your windows. The drawbacks are there that can only be four of them, and you can't easily rename them.

One possible alternative is [TidyTabs](https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/tidytabs).

It allows organizing and managing regular application windows using tabs. 
It adds a tab bar over any regular application window and you can drag other widows to it to group them together, while simultaneously keeping them available in the task bar at all times.

As far as I know you can't rename them but you can group them to the respective ticket window.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the standard Windows 10 multiple desktop does not meet my requirements, and TidyTabs, although being a nice try, is still too limited. Are you aware of other tools in that direction?